# Trouble with bigtofront when opening a child form from another child form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, forms, winforms

I have a C# project and trying to open a child form (`form3`) from another child form (`form2`) but `form2` goes aways behind to the parent's (`form1`) objects.

As you can see, when I open my `form2`, it hides the `form1` objects:
[image]

But when I click in the `button1` and open the `form3` and close the `form2`, `form3` goes behind the `form1` objects:
[image]

What should I do to solve this problem? `Form3` should also hide `form1` objects!

These are my code lines from `button1` in `form2`:

```
FormConsultaNome form = new FormConsultaNome();

Form1 form1 = new Form1();

form.MdiParent = Form1.ActiveForm;

form.Show();

this.Close();
```

Comment: in your sample code you are opening a form1, not a form3 like you said at the beginning

Comment: Sorry! FormConsultaNome is my form3. The line "form1 form1 = new form1" i was using in a test, but i'm opening the form3 that is just named form in the sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "right" way to bring a Windows Forms Application to the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463417/what-is-the-right-way-to-bring-a-windows-forms-application-to-the-foreground)