# VB - How to bring an application to the front?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to make a program that will run on a system. The program will launch a driver on startup, which displays a cmd window. I am trying to get my program to come back to the front after it opens this. I have tried using a few different things such as:

```
Me.BringToFront
Me.Activate
Me.Show
```

However, none of these have worked so far, does anyone know of another way I can do this?

Comment: `Me.TopMost = True` then `Me.Activate()` then `Me.TopMost = False`.

Comment: There are a bunch of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5282588/3110834).

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: If you mean to *obscure* the cmd Window, maybe you can just *hide* it (run the Process without a Window, if possible, and/or use `[Process].StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for this, this works brilliantly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "right" way to bring a Windows Forms Application to the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463417/what-is-the-right-way-to-bring-a-windows-forms-application-to-the-foreground)