# How to bring secondary window behind primary window?

Tags: c++, c++builder

While adding a secondary window (TForm) to a project written with Embarcadero C++Builder 10.4, I have the problem where that secondary window is always in front of the main one. That is, when clicking on the primary window, the secondary window loses focus but remains on top of the primary window.

I have tried changing the `BorderStyle` property, the `PopupMode` property, and I even tried to call the secondary window's `SendToBack()` method when the primary window activates. Nothing changes.

The secondary window is created with a `NULL` owner, and it is shown through it's `Show()` method.

The question is simple: How can I make the active window (TForm) on top of the other windows (TForm)?

[image: Primary window behind secondary]
(Primary TForm should not be behind secondary TForm when primary is active.)

Comment: There is WinAPI function, SetForegroundWindow, call it on the primary window

Comment: That's a good suggestion, alas it does not work :(

Comment: Just a guess, see if you call it on a child window. It must be the topmost parent, or frame window if is mdi.  Also it will not work if secondary is shown modally.
There is a discussion about setting the foreground window https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463417/what-is-the-right-way-to-bring-a-windows-forms-application-to-the-foreground

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior.

With `Application->MainFormOnTaskBar` set to `true`, when the secondary `TForm` is creating its window, and that Form's `FormStyle` is `fsNormal`, and the Form is not being shown modal, then its `PopupMode` is ignored and its owner window (in Win32 API terms, not VCL terms) gets set to the `Application->MainForm` window.

When a window has an owner window assigned, it can't ever go behind its owner.

To do what you are asking for (without switching to an MDI design), you need to instead have the hidden `TApplication` window be the owner of your secondary window, then you will be able to freely switch between your two windows.  To accomplish that, you can either:

- set `Application->MainFormOnTaskBar` to `false` (not advisable on Vista+ systems, as it will also disable a lot of other VCL behaviors that are needed for proper Vista+ interactions)
- use the `TApplication::OnGetMainFormHandle` event to provide the desired owner window, in this case `Application->Handle`
- have the secondary `TForm` class override the virtual `CreateParams()` method and set `Params.WndParent` to `Application->Handle`.

Comment: Thank you for that information. For the second option, when and how many times is the event `TApplication::OnGetMainFormHandle` invoked? Same thing with the third option: when should `Application->Handle` be set, and is that applicable for multiple secondary windows?

Comment: "*when and how many times is the event TApplication::OnGetMainFormHandle invoked?*" - any time the `TApplication::MainFormHandle` property is read. Look at the VCL's source code to find all the places, but I do know it happens during `TForm` window creation, and various dialog box activations (usually if `Application->ModalPopupMode` is `pmNone` or `Application->ActiveFormHandle` is null). "*Same thing with the third option*" - whenever the Form's `HWND` is (re)created. "*when should `Application->Handle` be set*" - whenever you don't want a Form's window to depend on another Form's window.